# ngtools module buildable after migration to Angular 14

Tags: webpack, upgrade, ivy, angular14, ngtools

I have upgraded my Angular 12 project to Angular 13 without any problems but then when I wanted to pass from angular 13 to Angular 14 I encountered problems with @ngtools. Complete log here:

```
./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.

./src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Emit attempted before Angular Webpack plugin initialization.

Error: Failed to initialize Angular compilation - The target entry-point "@ngbmodule/material-carousel" has missing dependencies:
 - @angular/compiler/src/core
```

I have tried to delete node_modules and package-lock.json, npm cache clean --force but it didn't help. I couldn't find any similar questions or problems anywhere else.
Thanks

Comment: Hello @LaCodeM, how did you solve the issue? I am facing the same issue while upgrading from angular 13 to angular 14

Comment: No I didn't, sorry I am not able to help. If I manage to find a solution I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi @LaCodeM, did you find a solution to this error? I am experiencing the same after upgrading my app to the latest version of Angular.

Comment: Still no, sorry. I will update my answer if I ever find solution.

Comment: Hi @LaCodeM were was able solve it?

Comment: still no, I will update my answer if I ever come back to it.